# Join two lists in sharepoint using linked view in Sharepoint designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list-view

I have 3 lists:

1. Contract No: Fields[Title]
2. Contract Info: [Contract No(lookup), Col1,Col2,Col3]
3. Contract Ops: [Contract No(lookup), Col4,Col5,Col6]

I need to display join of last 2 list i.e. Contract Info & Contract Ops

**Data in Contract No list:**

Ct0023

Ct0078

**Data in Contract Info list:**

Ct0023 |  A1  |  A2  |  A3

Ct0078 |  A4  |  A5  |  A6

**Data in Contract Ops list:**

Ct0023 | B1 | B2 | B3

Ct0023 | B4 | B5 | B6

Ct0078 | B7 | B8 | B9

Ct0078 | B10 | B11 | B12

**----->Expected Output<------**

Ct0023 | A1 | A2 | A3 | B1 | B2 | B3

Ct0023 | A1 | A2 | A3 | B4 | B5 | B6

Ct0078 | A4 | A5 | A6 | B7 | B8 | B9

Ct0078 | A4 | A5 | A6 | B10 | B11 | B12

I Need out of the box solution for this and using SharePoint 2013 online.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The out of the box solution is to add app parts of the 3 lists onto a page and connect them via connections in the web part properties. Then by selecting a contract, it filters the other 2 lists.

Comment: Thanks for reply Eric. Here tabular view is required, for reporting purpose.

Comment: Then it isn't going to be an out of the box approach then, you are going to have to roll something custom, like a data view web part or a client side web part from JSOM or REST calls to your lists

Comment: Hi Eric, I am trying to join the lists using linked  data source in SP designer.will let you know if it works for me.

Comment: Hey Eric, I used linked data source to join. I have posted the solution in answers section. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used **linked data source** for this requirement.

In SharePoint designer, you can create combined view of two lists.

create linked source using 2 lists as source.
Open a web part page in SharePoint designer and this linked data view.

Now you will see columns from one list added in view.

Click on data source details tab and select field in second list. Add them as a **joined item**. It will open a pop up saying 'select common field'. I selected Contract No field. Click ok to add the field.

Similarly add other fields and you are done.

You also need to add headers for these columns explicitly.